# LINQ - Select Statement - The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: linq

I am trying to achieve the following...

```
 _4S.NJB_Request request =
                (from r in db.NJB_Requests
                 where r.RequestId == referenceId
                 select r).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Getting the following exception...

```
    Message:
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.


StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at DAL.SqlDataProvider.MarkNJBPCRequestAsComplete(Int32 referenceId, Int32 processState)
```

I have verified that 'referenceId' does have a value.

Anyone know why this would happen in a select statement?

Thanks!

EDIT:  r.RequestId = NOT NULL Int, referenceId = int

Comment: do you have other int32 fieds in _4S.NJB_Request class?

Comment: what are types of referenceId and r.RequestId?

Comment: I think you might want .FirstOrDefault() instead of .Take(1).SingleOrDefault()

Comment: @Hightechrider - Changed it to FirstOrDefault and I am still getting the same error...any other ideas?

Comment: Please show us what _4S.NJB_Request and the NJB_Requests table looks like.  Is there an Int32 field in _4S.NJB that's a nullable value in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is r.RequestId nullable? Then you would use:

```
 _4S.NJB_Request request =
                (from r in db.NJB_Requests
                 where r.RequestId == (int?)referenceId
                 select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Are your dc up to date with the database? Perhaps you have a null in the database that is being assigned to an int becuase your model is not synced with the database

Comment: @Kurresmack - RequestId is not nullable as it is the Primary Key for the table

Comment: Are your dc up to date with the database? Perhaps you have a null in the database that is being assigned to an int becuase your model is not synced with the database

Comment: looks like my local db was not in sync with the production db..thanks for your help sir..

Answer (score 0):

I think the Take call is redundant and keeping the SingleOrDefault from saving you from the exception, try replacing Take(1).SingleOrDefault with FirstOrDefault:

```
(from r in db.NJB_Requests
                 where r.RequestId == referenceId
                 select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

edit: changed SingleOrDefault to FirstOrDefault to avoid getting an exception if more than 1 item is returned.

Comment: That will throw an expcetion if there are more that 1 element in the list. Instead you would use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: "That will throw an expcetion if there are more that 1 element in the list." -- Then use FirstOrDefault


edit: Heh, I see you updated your comment to make it appear that you suggested FirstOrDefault initially...updating mine to show how it read when I replied.

Comment: @Kurresmack & @kekekela - Changed it to FirstOrDefault and I am still getting the same error...any other ideas?

Comment: Actually I edited my comment and when I got back from editing I saw that you had replied allready ;)

thiag0 check my other answer

Comment: What type is referenceId and what type is Request.ID...might want to just edit that into the OP since it looks like someone else already asked the same thing in the comments up there.